# Неправильно отрисовывается объект в pygame

Tags: python, pygame, порядок

Если все обобщить то при нажатии кнопки мыши на месте клика должен появиться круг и там же остаться. Но в моем случае экран обновляется и круг на следующую итерацию пропадает

```
import pygame


display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))


def main():
    Run = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    board = Board()

    board.create_piece(display, board.get_checker_position()
                       )  # создает список с позициями шашек

    while Run:
        clock.tick(60)
        board.draw_win(display)  # отрисовывает поле
        board.updatepiece(display)  # отрисовывает шашки
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Run = False

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    pygame.draw.circle(display, GREEN, event.pos, 15)
                    pygame.display.update()

        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Объект класса Board рисует поле и отрисовывает элементы(шашки)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
def main():
    Run = True

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    board = Board()

    board.create_piece(display, board.get_checker_position()
                       )  # создает список с позициями шашек
    board.draw_win(display)
    board.updatepiece(display)
    while Run:
        clock.tick(60)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                Run = False

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    board.draw_win(display)
                    board.updatepiece(display)
                    pygame.draw.circle(display, GREEN, event.pos, 15)
                    pygame.display.update()

        pygame.display.update()
    pygame.quit()
```